# Best way to iterate through Excel rows and delete based on met criteria

Tags: python, for-loop, openpyxl

So I have a very simple for loop that deletes rows if a value in column 9 is equal to the employee name:

```
import openpyxl, os

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Opportunities.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet = wb['OpportunityList']

for rowNum in range(2, sheet.max_row):
    if sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 9).value == 'Employee Name':
        print('Deleting row ' + str(rowNum))
        sheet.delete_rows(rowNum)

wb.save('1.xlsx')
```

The problem I'm having is that let's say row 20 meets the criteria and is deleted, well row 21 now becomes row 20.  So the for loop will progress with rowNum 21 and if the row that used to be 21 and is now 20 also meets the criteria, well that row won't be deleted because the for loop already scanned row 20 and can't go back.

How do I solve this problem?  Could putting the rows in a list and then deleting them possibly work? Or would that cause the same problem?  Thanks in advance

Comment: `for c in reversed(sheet['9']): if c.value == "Employee Name": sheet.delete_rows(c.row)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from the bottom and work your way up!

```
for rowNum in range(sheet.max_row, 1, -1):
    if sheet.cell...
```

Comment: Awesome!  Doesn't need the -1 after sheet.max_row, but otherwise works perfectly.  Thanks!!

Comment: Interesting. @user1452574 you were excluding the row sheet.max_row in your question. Using my answer without the -1 on sheet.max_row includes that number in the range, which afaik is out of bounds for the sheet.

Comment: Yeah that's just me being an idiot, lol.  I should've had sheet.max_row+1 to include that row in the for loop

Comment: So I just ran it and took about 2 minutes to delete about 2000 rows.  A bit slower than I'd like, but works nonetheless!